# What does some function evaluated at $0^+$ mean?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

Let's say there's an expression like this:$$a = p(x)|_{x=0^+}$$ Is it the equivalent of $$a=\lim_{x\to 0^+}p(x)$$ or does it/can it mean something else?

Comment: That's a very uncommon notation, I've never seen it before. How about asking the author?

Comment: @freakish Physicists write something like this a lot.  It is not that uncommon.  To answer the OP's question, yes it means the limit you wrote.  Sometimes you will see $p(x)\big|_{x=0^-}^{x=0^+}$ too.  That expression means $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}p(x)-\lim_{x\to 0^-}p(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it used in two contexts, so you might have to match this with what your situation is. Generally its used more in a physics sense than a pure mathematical one.

The first interpretation is what you described
$$
p(0^+) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} p(x)
$$

which is equivilent to the second definition. This second definition is certainly more loose, but has its usages in electrical engineering, physics, etc.

> $p(0^+)$ is the value of $p(t)$ at the instant immediately after $t=0$

I've personally seen this used in the context of electrical signals when a switch is flipped on "the instant after" $t=0$, which I'll admit doesn't make much sense, but is sufficient enough to solve the problem at hand